# Change of variable in an integral. How do I solve this particular one?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I've been trying to solve this exercise for a little while now...
 Maybe you can be of a little help!
The question is as follows,

Calculate

$$\int\int_D\frac{dx_1dx_2}{x_1+x_2}$$

Where the region D is bounded by the lines:

$x_1+x_2=1$, $x_1+x_2=4$, $x_1=0$, $x_2=0$.

Use the transformation $x_1=u_1-u_1u_2$, $x_2=u_1u_2$

I hope you can help me figure out this one.

Answer (score 0):

First plot the lines to get an idea of what the trapezoid looks like. This will also tell you what the integrations bounds would be, but that's less important.

Next apply the suggested transformation to see what that rectangle looks like. This will tell you what the bounds for the transformed integral shall be, which is vital.

Then determine what the Jaccobian matrix (and hence its determinant) shall be.

Finally , integrate. Do the above right, and this part will be easy.